# WPF Binding Color Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, binding

I am very new to WPF and working through a few sample controls and trying to adapt them in order to familiarize myself on how things work.
My current task is I have a LinearGradientBrush code below

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ThumbBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#c1dbe8"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#008fc7"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#066caa"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

I would like to convert this to a property so that colours can be amended. My thought was that I could simply create a Property for each Color

```
public Color MyThumbColor1 { get; set; }
public Color MyThumbColor2 { get; set; }
public Color MyThumbColor3 { get; set; }
```

Then bind each color to the respective GradientStop

```
<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{Binding MyThumbColor1}"/>
<GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{Binding MyThumbColor1}"/>
<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding MyThumbColor1}"/>
```

This isn't working therefore any guidance on how to bind a color Property would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the current DataContext - i.e. the object that is used as the source object of the Bindings? Where are the source properties set?

Comment: To create a binding, you must specify, in addition to the property, the source object.
By default (that is, if not specified) it uses the object from the DataContext.
In addition, in the class where the properties are declared, so that the bindings are auto-updated when they change, the INPC interface must be implemented and notifying through it about the change in the value of properties.
Show more details of your implementation for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I forgot to include

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

just after InitializeComponent(); on the NewControl.xaml.cs file